# Covering zeroes of quadratic forms by linear forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Consider a quadratic form
$$Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_ix_j,$$
where $a_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_i\in A$ for some $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such what $|A|=k$.

**Question.** What is the smallest number of linear forms
$$L_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_i b_ix_i, \quad b_i\in \mathbb{R},$$
that are guaranteed to cover all the zeroes of $Q$? That is - what is the minimal number $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such for any such $Q$ all zeroes of $Q$ (elements of $A^n$) lie in the set of zeroes of some linear forms $L_1,\ldots, L_m$ in those same variables? Could it be that $m$ does not depend on neither $k$ nor $n$? Furthermore, could it be that $m=2$ (which is the case if $Q$ splits into a product of two linear forms) or $3$?

Since the sharp value of $m$ could be difficult to find, all boils down to giving upper bounds of the form
$$m\leq f(k,n).$$

Comment: Surely $m$ will tend to infinity as $k$ becomes larger, because the full quadric (i.e., with $A = \mathbb{R}$) cannot be covered by finitely many hyperplanes in general.

Comment: Assume $n=2$, then the zero set of $Q$ is a conic when $Q$ is non-degenerate, and every line will intersect it in at most $2$ points, so you would need roughly $\frac{|A|^2}{2}$ lines to cover it. When $Q$ is degenerate you need at most $2$ lines.

Comment: @A. Bailleul, would something similar be true for $n>2$? Even something not so optimal, but, say, some kind of polynomial bound in terms of $|A|$?

Comment: It is still true that a line will intersect your zero set in at most two points, unless said zero set contains that line. For example the cone $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ in $3$-dimensional space contains infinitely many lines.